# Qual a diferença entre classe parametrizada, multiobjetos e collections?

Tags: java, classes, engenharia-de-software, objetos, collection

Bom, eu sei os conceitos de cada uma. Apenas não estou sabendo diferenciá-las. Por exemplo, uma classe parametrizada é uma classe que é utilizada para definir outras classes, e uma collection pode ser representada por uma classe parametrizada. No entanto, qual a diferença entre elas? Afinal. em Java, uma classe parametrizada equivale à uma Collection. Quanto a multiobjetos, sei também que eles podem representar o lado muitos numa associação um para muitos, mas também não consigo enxergar as diferenças entre esses  três conceitos. Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço!

Answer (score -2):

Uma Collection pode conter tipos primitivos, como ints.. Já o "multiobjeto" é uma collection com generics, por padrão, todo argumento que for dentro do generics tem que ser um Objeto, ou seja classe, classe que herda do Object (em java) por exemplo: List<String> ou List<SuaClasse>. Classe parametrizada eu sei lá.

Fonte: Cap.7 Livro do Bezerra